# Careers tag search should only search tags

Tags: bug, jobs

This URL specifies a tag search for Go jobs ("tag/go"):

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/go?sort=p

However most of the results aren't tagged "go." (Tags are indicated by blue rectangles.)

Instead, results include jobs that merely refer to the keyword in the body of the post. A tag search should only display careers that are tagged with the search term.

Note that this is true of any term, not just "go," which is admittedly more generic. Searches for "ruby" or "python," for example, reveal the same issue--results that aren't tagged with "ruby" or "python."

A tag search should only search tags, exactly as implied by the URL.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. I read the linked question before posting, and it claims that the issue would be "eliminated" over a year ago, and given that it wasn't, an old question has little chance of being seen or remedied. But don't let that get in the way of your OCD. (One would think people would have better things to do with their precious time, but one would be incorrect.)

Answer (score 3):

This is by design. Our clients who post jobs might or might not have specifics on the technologies, or use tags at all. There is less rigor and review than on Stack Overflow.

So our “tag” searches are in fact full-text searches. This nets out better, but is of course imperfect.

“go” is a good example of where it breaks down. (True of the internet in general, btw, which is why you see “golang” a lot.) We might be able to special-case that one.

Comment: +1 for the option to "special case", didn't think about such option :)

Comment: And just to confound things further: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/employer/go

Comment: Thanks Matt. I anticipated the response about "go," which is why I included the Ruby and Python examples as well, and considered not using the Go example at all to avoid that. As a searcher, it would be great to find jobs that only focus on a specific language, and not those included by companies trying to piggy-back on the latest technology. (I've seen jobs for other languages like PHP or Java that will include a line along the lines of: "Like Ruby? Us too!" Which of course has nothing to do with the actual day-to-day requirements of the position.)

Comment: I forgot to mention, we do weight the job title and tags more highly than the body text. Jobs tagged “go” or “ruby” do get a de facto boost.

Comment: @MattSherman this is a terrible UX for searchers :( An attempt to tag search `ecmascript-6` (a far cry from `go`) returns 1256 results. From the first page it's obvious that there are results (I'm guessing the vast majority) that aren't tagged with that or even its synonym `es6`. The results are, for practical purposes, useless. I respectfully disagree that the current system nets out better. It would be a far better UX to allow users to opt-in to tag search. Full-text search is of course a sensible default when the user just enters keywords...

Comment: ...but being able to opt-in to tag search via `[whatever]` or some other means would vastly improve the UX. I'd credit users in general with understanding the concept that posters may not tag their posts well (not to mention many of them are constantly fixing that very problem on StackOverflow). That's easily solved by doing a keyword search if you want to wade through a lot of stuff. Currently there's no way to search according to tags that posters *have* used. It shortchanges users and the posters that *do* do good tagging. http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/ecmascript-6